# What is prefixed shard in ODL?

Tags: opendaylight

Each time when MD-SAL starts it creates shard member-1-shard-prefix-configuration-shard-config.  This shard is created automatically. ODL does not have any explicit configuration for it.
What this shard is for? Is it only for internal usage or it can be used by a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefixed shard feature is intended to allow the data store to be sharded more granularly at any level in the yang tree rather than just top-level yang modules. There are cluster-admin RPCs to configure prefixed shards. However the feature should probably be considered alpha at this point and the original contributors abandoned it so no one is actively working on it.